# Delphi - setting Full Control on Registry Key

Tags: delphi, permissions, registry

I'm using the following code (found online) to set Full Control for a key in the Registry:

```
procedure TForm1.bnSetRegistryFCClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  SID: PSID;
  peUse, cchDomain, cchName, dwResult: DWORD;
  Name, Domain: array of Char;
  pDACL: PACL;
  pEA: PEXPLICIT_ACCESS_W;//
  sObject: String;
begin
  sObject := 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland';
  SID := nil;
  Win32Check(ConvertStringSidToSidA(PChar('S-1-5-32-545'), SID));        //    S-1-5-32-545='users';  S-1-1-0='everyone'
  cchName := 0;
  cchDomain := 0;

  if (not LookupAccountSid(nil, SID, nil, cchName, nil, cchDomain, peUse)) and (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
  begin
    SetLength(Name, cchName);
    SetLength(Domain, cchDomain);
    if LookupAccountSid(nil, SID, @Name[0], cchName, @Domain[0], cchDomain, peUse) then
    begin
      pEA := AllocMem(SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
      BuildExplicitAccessWithName(pEA, PChar(Name), GENERIC_ALL,GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT);
      dwResult := SetEntriesInAcl(1, pEA, nil, pDACL);
      if dwResult = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      begin
        dwResult := SetNamedSecurityInfo(pChar(sObject), SE_REGISTRY_KEY, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, pDACL, nil);
        if dwResult <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
          ShowMessage('SetNamedSecurityInfo failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
        LocalFree(Cardinal(pDACL));
      end
      else
        ShowMessage('SetEntriesInAcl failed: ' + SysErrorMessage(dwResult));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

SetNamedSecurityInfo returns an error 87 and fails to set the permissions which I think means one of the parameters is wrong. If I use this same code but using SE_FILE_OBJECT instead of SE_REGISTRY_KEY, I can set permissions on given folders successfully. I get the same result whether I use SID S-1-5-32-545 = 'users' or S-1-1-0 = 'everyone'.

Any help much appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Tell us more about the execution environment. 32 bit or 64 bit. Which OS. Which Delphi.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE5. The app itself is a 32-bit app but I've also tried compiling it as a 64-bit app with the same result. I've tried running it on both a Win7 64-bit machine and a Win7 32-bit machine with the same result.

Comment: In a 64 bit process the key is under Wow6432Node. I suspect redirection could be an issue. I'd test this code on a non redirected key.

Comment: Yes, I should be avoiding the redirection issue when I run it on the Win7 32-bit machine but I get the same error 87.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of your registry key is wrong.  When making an API call that uses `SE_OBJECT_TYPE` you have to use a set of specific literals in place of the full `HKEY_...` format.

```
sObject := 'MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Borland';
```

For reference : [MSDN - SE_OBJECT_TYPE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The names of registry keys must use the following literal strings to
>   identify the predefined registry keys: "CLASSES_ROOT", "CURRENT_USER",
>   "MACHINE", and "USERS".

Comment: That is brilliant! Worked immediately!

Comment: @user3387569 Glad it helped.  To be honest, I don't understand why Microsoft decided to use this rather nonintuitive shorthand format for these calls.  The natural instinct is to use the actual name of the registry key.

Comment: The ways of Microsoft are often beyond understanding :-)

Comment: Indeed, just look at how they implemented 64bit Windows, where "64bit" files are found in "System32" and "32bit" files are in "SysWOW64"